# Kill other roscore/master processes on bourn shell

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I keep getting this error message when trying to run roscore:

```
roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.
```

However, I only have one terminal window open. How could there already be a roscore running? I've tried quitting Terminal and restarting it and I've tried restarting my computer. It doesn't matter what I do - my computer thinks there is a roscore running even though there are no terminal windows open with roscore running in them. Is there a way to kill this invisible roscore so that I can run one in a window?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172879/kill-other-roscore/master-processes-on-bourn-shell/) by [ROSwithNao](https://answers.ros.org/users/18795/roswithnao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ToughMind](https://answers.ros.org/users/30487/toughmind/) on 2017-06-04**:
I met the same problem. There is no roscore or rosmaster running. But I met this error whenever I run roscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the terminal you can do:

```
killall -9 roscore
```

and also:

```
killall -9 rosmaster
```

that will completely stop them

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 38

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-19**:
Without OP specifying the OS/platform, I think this can be marked as answer. [@dornhege's answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/172879/kill-other-roscoremaster-processes-on-bourn-shell/?answer=172881#post-id-172881) explains well the reason `roscore` could be running headless.

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2019-05-28**:
The `killall -9 rosmaster` works effectively!

**Comment by [cat_in_box](https://answers.ros.org/users/44444/cat_in_box/) on 2019-08-01**:
thanks - did the trick

**Comment by [scottie](https://answers.ros.org/users/140873/scottie/) on 2023-02-27**:
I realised that even after killing 'rosmaster' there is one more ROS related process running.

`killall -9 rosmaster && killall -9 rosout` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be from another user.
If it does happen even after a reboot, maybe you put something like roscore in your init files like .bashrc.

Check with e.g. rosnode list if there really is a rosmaster running.wh

`ps aux|grep roscore` should show you who started it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7